# SequenceEqual is true but HashSet.SetEquals is false

Tags: c#, linq, set, sequence, equality

I've been experimenting with implementing Set equality (ie List comparisons where the order is irrelevant) and after reading SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098/comparing-two-collections-for-equality) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945158/set-equality-in-linq), wrote the following simple extension:

```
    public static bool SetEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        if (enumerable == null && other == null)
            return true;

        if (enumerable == null || other == null)
            return false;

        var setA = new HashSet<T>(enumerable);
        return setA.SetEquals(other);
    }
```

However, I came across a simple data structure for which this approach does not work, while Enumerable.SequenceEqual does.

```
    public class Test : IEquatable<Test>
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public List<Test> RelatedTest { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != typeof(Test)) return false;

            return Equals((Test)obj);
        }

        public bool Equals(Test other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

            return other.Id.Equals(Id) &&
                   RelatedTest.SetEqual(other.RelatedTest);
        }
    }
```

Given this object, this test succeeds:

```
    [Test]
    public void SequenceEqualTest()
    {
        var test1 = new List<Test> {new Test()};
        var test2 = new List<Test> {new Test() };

        Assert.That(test1.SequenceEqual(test2), Is.True);
    }
```

But this test fails:

```
    [Test]
    public void SetEqualTest()
    {
        var test1 = new List<Test> {new Test()};
        var test2 = new List<Test> {new Test()};

        Assert.That(test1.SetEqual(test2), Is.True);
    }
```

Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you didn't override `GetHashCode` in your `Test` class, so the HashSet is unable to effectively group items into buckets according to possible equality.  See this question for more details: [Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c)